# Combining three scripts

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I need to combine the below script. They are separately working fine. If any one condition success then need to ignore the remaining two.

```
a="primary"
b=`virtinfo -a |grep name |'awk' '{ print $3}'`
if [ "$a" == "$b" ]
then
echo "`hostname` I'm Control Domain"
ldm list | awk '{ print $1}'
fi

a=`cat /etc/nodename`
b=`virtinfo -a |grep name |'awk' '{ print $3}'`
if [ "$a" = "$b" ]
then
echo "`hostname` I'm Ldom"
virtinfo -a |grep Control
zoneadm list|grep -v global
fi

if [ ! "`/usr/bin/zonename`" = 'global' ]
then
echo " `hostname` im in a Local Zone"
fi
```

Comment: a="primary"
b=`virtinfo -a |grep name |'awk' '{ print $3}'`
if [ "$a" == "$b" ]
then
echo "`hostname` I'm Control Domain"
ldm list | awk '{ print $1}'
fi

a=`cat /etc/nodename`
b=`virtinfo -a |grep name |'awk' '{ print $3}'`
if [ "$a" = "$b" ]
then
echo "`hostname` I'm Ldom"
virtinfo -a |grep Control
zoneadm list|grep -v global
fi

if [ ! "`/usr/bin/zonename`" = 'global' ]
then
echo " `hostname` im in a Local Zone"
fi

Comment: What shell is this supposed to run in?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your logic correctly.

This is assuming that a machine can not be in more than one domain (or zone, or whatever you call them) at once.  If a machine is not in "Control Domain" it goes on to check if it's in "Ldom". If that's not the case, it goes on to check if it's in a "Local Zone".  If nothing matches, it displays "I'm totally lost".

```
virtname="$( virtinfo -a | awk '/name/ { print $3 }' )"
myname="$( hostname )"

if [[ "$virtname" == "primary" ]]; then 
  printf '%s, I am Control Domain\n' "$myname"

  ldm list | awk '{ print $1 }'

elif [[ "$virtname" == "$( cat /etc/nodename )" ]]; then
  printf '%s, I am Ldom\n' "$myname"

  virtinfo -a  | grep "Control"
  zoneadm list | grep -v "global"

elif [[ "$( /usr/bin/zonename )" != "global" ]]; then
  printf '%s, I am in a Local Zone\n' "$myname"
else
  printf '%s, I am totally lost\n' "$myname"
fi
```

It's also obviously assuming a shell that understands `[[ ... ]]`. If that's not the case, then it's trivial to fix.

Note, this code is entierly untested since I don't have access to `virtinfo` etc.

Comment: Thanks for modifying it, it working only on physical machine apart from this its not working on remining two.
 In control domain its working fine.
root@cidcsspinf113:/tmp# ./new3.sh
cidcsspinf113 I'm Control Domain
NAME
cidcsspdb005
cidcsspdb034
cidcsspovm040
cidcsspweb007
root@cidcsspinf113

in Ldom i am getting the below error.

root on cidcsspovm040:</tmp>
# ./test5.sh
./test5.sh: [[: not found
./test5.sh: [[: not found
./test5.sh: [[: not found
$( hostname ), I am totally lost
root on cidcsspovm040

Comment: In Local Zone seprately working fine

root on cidcsspapp075:</tmp>
# ./test2.sh
./test2.sh: [[: not found
./test2.sh: [[: not found
./test2.sh: [[: not found
$( hostname ), I am totally lost
root on cidcsspapp075:</tmp>
# ! "`/usr/bin/zonename`" = 'global'
!: not found
root on cidcsspapp075:</tmp>
# if [ ! "`/usr/bin/zonename`" = 'global' ]
> then
> echo " `hostname` im in a Local Zone"
> fi
 cidcsspapp075 im in a Local Zone
root on cidcsspapp075:</tmp>
#

Comment: @pandi What shell are you running this in? Try it with Bash. Add a line at the top saying `#!/bin/bash`.  It will also work with `ksh` and `zsh` (I think).

Comment: Thanks lot its working fine in /bin/ksh shell
opsunix(opsunix) on cidcsspapp075 : </tmp>
$ echo "$SHELL"
/bin/ksh

opsunix(opsunix) on cidcsspapp075 : </tmp>

root on cidcsspapp075:</tmp>
# ./test2.sh
./test2.sh: [[: not found
./test2.sh: [[: not found
./test2.sh: [[: not found
$( hostname ), I am totally lost
root on cidcsspapp075:</tmp>
# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root)
root on cidcsspapp075:</tmp>
# Thanks so so muchhhhhhhhhhhh